# What operator is <> in VBA

Tags: vba, operators

I was studying some [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) code and came across this:

```
If DblBalance <> 0 Then
```

I can't figure out what operator this is, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is the "not equal" operator, i.e. the equivalent of `!=` in pretty much every other language.

Answer (score 8):

***Not Equal To***

---

Before C came along and popularized `!=`, languages tended to use `<>` for *not equal to*.

At least, the various dialects of Basic did, and they predate C.

An even older and more unusual case is Fortran, which uses `.NE.`, as in `X .NE. Y`.

Answer (score 8):

It means not equal to, as the others said..

I just wanted to say that I read that as "greater than or lesser than".

e.g.

```
let x = 12

if x <> 0 then
    //code
```

In this case 'x' is greater than (that's the '>' symbol) 0.

Hope this helps. :D

Answer (score 3):

It is an "INEQUALITY" operator. [Get a list of comparison operators in VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators)

Answer (score 1):

in sql... we use it for "not equals"... I am guessing, its the same in VB aswell.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA this is `<> (Not equal to)` operator.

The result becomes true if `expression1 <> expression2`

The result becomes false if `expression1 = expression2`

[Additional Reading 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx)

[Additional Reading 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

This is an Inequality operator.

Also,this might be helpful for future: [Operators listed by Functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is the exact same content provided by Abubakkar 3 years earlier than you.